# Can't access to Gitlab Instance on local network

Tags: networking, localhost, gitlab

I'm currently having some problems with my self-hosted Gitlab instance.

My problem is that I am not able to access it from any computers on the same network. Both the Gitlab website and the CLI (push/pull/etc) are getting a timeout error when I try accessing it.

The curiosity is that from **ANYWHERE** else, I'm able to access it and to push/pull/etc ...

I have a nginx configuration that redirects 0.0.0.0:80 to 443 and that redirect 443 to localhost:${MY_GITLAB_PORT}

I already tried to use `nmap` to see the open port and I can see that both 80 and 443 are open which is normal.

Do you have any idea of why I can't access to my Gitlab instance only when I'm on the same local network ?

Comment: Hard to tell, can you give some more info about your network? Do you have a firewall running? Can you connect to other services or is it just GitLab? Is your router blocking intra-network traffic?

Comment: Feels like the problem is irrelevant to GitLab per se, and is bound to networking. Do you have any proxy settings defined in your LAN maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just solved my problems, It was due to the Google Wifi I used.

Google Wifi was creating his own network which couldn't access to my Gitlab Instance's network (which was in Ethernet)

I had to create a new route to allow Google Wifi to access to the other network